# A couple of new tag merge requests (Nov '11)

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

- I recently invented both a [forms](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forms) and [paperwork](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paperwork) tag. They should be synonyms, so far they're used the same number of times, just once I think, but they'll surely be used more. I think "paperwork" might be a bit more general so should be the main tag.
- Somebody invented a new [law](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) but we already have [legal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal). "Law" is a perfectly good synonym and one wouldn't pop up as you type the other so I think we should make them official synonyms.

Answer (score 4):

[forms](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forms) --> [paperwork](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paperwork) - Done.
[law](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) --> [legal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) - Done.

Comment: Thanking you good sir!

Comment: Oh my, what an old post